# Error when adding pointer to class in different namespace?

Tags: c++, pointers, namespaces

For some reason I keep getting 
"../Svc/../Drv/Timer.h:18:12: error: 'svc' has not been declared" when I compile. Can't figure out why...

Timer.h File

```
#include "../Svc/TimerManager.h"

namespace drv {

class Timer {
public:
    void Init(svc::TimerManager *aTimerMan);

private:
    svc::TimerManager *timerMan;

    };

} /* namespace drv */
```

TimerManager.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "../Drv/Timer.h"

namespace svc {

/*
 *
 */
class TimerManager {
public:
    uint8_t msec10;
    uint8_t sec;
    uint8_t min;
    uint8_t hour;

    void Init();
    void IncrementTime();

private:
    drv::Timer timer;

};

} /* namespace svc */
```

Comment: What happens if you write ``::svc::TimerManager`` ? Note the ``::`` in front.

Comment: Compiler : error: 'svc' in namespace '::' does not name a type. When I add the :: in front

Comment: Is that an embedded compiler, such as Diab by any chance? I know some have problems with namespaces still.

Comment: @user2225104: all compilers have problems with circular dependencies.

Comment: Just noticed the circular stuff lol. Yeah - looks like the design needs some cleanup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both headers try to include each other, which is impossible.

Luckily, `Timer.h` doesn't do anything with `TimerManager` to require a complete definition; so don't include that header, just declare the class:

```
namespace svc {class TimerManager;}
```